# Android Calculate Distance Traveled

Tags: android

I am currently working on an application focused around fitness. The basic I idea is to allow to people to track their speed,distance,time. So far I have managed to get speed working by using location manager getSpeed(). I wanted to find out how I can get the distance traveled?
I looked for some samples but was bit confusing for me as I just started to work with android.
I would appreciate any help or advise , thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_track);

    start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    speed = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSpeed);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);



    //initialize location listener
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            getSpeed(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }

        //get the speed from the given location updates
        public void getSpeed(Location location) {
            currentSpeed = (location.getSpeed()*3600/1000);
            String convertedSpeed = String.format("%.2f",currentSpeed);
            speed.setText(convertedSpeed + "Km/h");
        }

        public void getDistance(Location location){

        }

    };
```

Comment: You could use [distanceBetween()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) method.

Comment: Prerak Sola ,how can I use it on when the location is changing all the time. I presume the distanceBeteew() is used on static location between point A and point B.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this:
http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html

For each location you get, you create a LatLng and added it to a ArrayList.
Then with this function it gets you the correct length:

```
SphericalUtil.computeLength(latLngs);
```

Gradle:

```
 dependencies {
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

EDIT:
You have an Arraylist locations = new ArrayList globally.
And in your "onLocationChanged" you add to the locations:

```
  @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        locations.add(location);
    }
```

Then when needed you do:

```
 for (Location loc :  locations){
     latLngs.add(new LatLng(loc.getLocation().getLat(), loc.getLocation().getLng()));
 }
 Double dist = SphericalUtil.computeLength(latLngs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //*****this is for log in and gcm reg id passsing in back end
private class communicate_server_for_get_2_position_duration extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    static final String TAG = "rvms";

    Context getcontext;
    String lat1 = null, lng1 = null, lat2 = null, lng2 = null;

    String getcontent_for_validate, content;

    public communicate_server_for_get_2_position_duration(Context context, double lat, double lng, double lat2, double lng2) {
        getcontext = context;
        lat1 = String.valueOf(lat);
        lng1 = String.valueOf(lng);
        this.lat2 = String.valueOf(lat2);
        this.lng2 = String.valueOf(lng2);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            finish();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        BufferedReader reader;
        String url_data = null;
        try {
            url_data = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=" + lat1 + "," + lng1 + "&destinations=" + lat2 + "," + lng2 + "&mode=driving&language=en-EN";
            url_data = url_data.replace("\n", "%20");
            url_data = url_data.replace(" ", "%20");
            url_data = url_data.replace("'", "%20");
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        Log.i("pavan", "url" + url_data);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_data);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            conection.setDoOutput(true);


            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line + "");

            }
            content = result.toString();
            System.out.print(result);
            System.out.println(content);
            getcontent_for_validate = content;


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        JSONObject jsonobj;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //Toast.makeText(context,"response "+result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String distance = null, duration = null;
        if (result != null) {
            if (content.equals("failure")) {


            } else {//ths is getting data for vehicl_list_unread_count code, client id,restapi_key
                JSONObject location1, location2;
                String location_string1 = null;
                try {
                    JSONObject ret = new JSONObject(getcontent_for_validate);
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"this is get content"+jsonobj.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //  System.out.println("this is get content"+jsonobj.toString());


                    try {
                        location1 = ret.getJSONArray("rows").getJSONObject(0);
                        location2 = location1.getJSONArray("elements").getJSONObject(0);


                        JSONObject get_distance = location2.getJSONObject("distance");
                        distance = get_distance.getString("text");

                        JSONObject get_duration = location2.getJSONObject("duration");
                        duration = get_duration.getString("text");

                        Log.d("test", "formattted address:" + location_string1);
                    } catch (JSONException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
                try {
                    if (key_for_intent_data_from.equals("from current location")) {
```

//fabBtn.show();
                            //String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                            /*Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
                            String formattedDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());*/
                            /*TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("etc/UTC");
                            DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);
                            inputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
                            DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm aa",Locale.US);
                            outputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);

```
                        Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
                        String output = outputFormat.format(date);*/

                        // fabBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                        //currentDateTimeString = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new java.util.Date());

                        duration_text_view.setText("\nPresent DATE/TIME: " + currentDateTimeString + "\nDevice DATE/TIME: " + deviceTime + "\nLOCATION: " + distance + " from your location point.");
                    } else {
                        String snackbar_data = null;


                        snackbar_data = "Date/Time:" + deviceTime + "\nLocation:" + distance + " from your location point.";

                        View parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.map);
                        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                                .make(parentLayout, snackbar_data, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                                .setAction("CLOSE", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {

                                    }
                                });
```

// Changing message text color
                            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.RED);

// Changing action button text color
                            View sbView = snackbar.getView();
                            TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
                            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            textView.setLines(5);
                            snackbar.show();

```
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }


        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getcontext, "Check net connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```