# How to use android distanceBetween() method

Tags: android

Hi recently I have been working with the application that requires to track the distance the person traveled while he is walking. I am using the location manager for getting the person coordinates ( lang and lat).

```
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
    };
```

How can I use the method distanceBetween() to get the actual distance traveled? 
I am confused how to distinguish starting position and end position, as location manager gives you the current position and keeps giving back new position every 5s ( thats what I configured to be on requestLocationUpdates() )

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I don't see any `distanceBetween()` method here. How is it defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Calculate Distance Traveled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719550/android-calculate-distance-traveled)

Comment: Where is the `distanceBetween()` and what have you tried already?

Comment: And, again, you're reposting. Stop that

Comment: its not defined yet, as the methods is coming from location class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double, double, double, double, float[])

Comment: Yes, it is defined. It's in the API. You have two of the parameters already for the new location, so you need to store the old Location

Comment: How to store old location if the location is getting updated at certain time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am confused how to distinguish starting position and end position, as location manager gives you the current position and keeps giving back new position every 5s

You already have the code available to get a new location, so you need to *save the old Location* and *calculate distance to new location* during every location update.

```
Location oldLoc, newLoc;
locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (oldLoc!=null) { 
            if (newLoc == null) { 
                newLoc = location; 
                // get distance 
                return; 
             } 
            // else, both not null 
            oldLoc = newLoc;
            newLoc = location;
            // get distance 
        } else { oldLoc = location; } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, and I am sorry asking same question ...just need to find the solution ASAP.

Comment: I'd use Location distanceTo method, not distance between anyway

Comment: is there a big difference between them ?

Comment: There's less parameters. Location1.distanceTo(Location2) makes more sense to me.. Besides, that method probably calls the other one

Comment: Ok, so then I would just need to store my past location as Location1 and new location as Location2 ? ...correct me if am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Something like that, yes. I think the code in my answer works. I didn't test it, though