# Calculate distance travelled in real time

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I want to get the distance in real time, I've found out a lot of posts on internet about it, but so far i haven't been able to make it work, and I'm not sure which is the best option. I also want to display the distance in a TextView.
And I'd like to know if I have to use "distanceTo" or "distancebetween"

So far this is what I have, I was following this but I got confused! 
[How to use android distanceBetween() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742439/how-to-use-android-distancebetween-method?rq=1)

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            Location oldLoc=0, newLoc=0;

            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            if(oldLoc!=null){
                if(newLoc == null){
                    newLoc = location;

                }
            }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                    Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Just increment the distance travelled each time a new Location comes in.

Use member variables to store the previous location, the distance travelled so far, and a reference to the TextView you want to update:

```
Location mPrevLocation = null;
float mDistanceTravelled = 0.0F;
TextView mDistanceTextView;
```

Then, use this code to keep track of the distance, and update the TextView:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (mPrevLocation != null) {
            mDistanceTravelled += mPrevLocation.distanceTo(location);
            mDistanceTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mDistanceTravelled));
        }
        mPrevLocation = location;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
};
```

Comment: There's something weird about it, i just give a step and it start counting and shows a "9.6852" quantity, how do i know if it is meters or centimeters?